# Native facebook app log in status in iOS

Tags: iphone

How to check if user is logged into the native facebook app or not in my another application in iPhone programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check that. The Facebook SDK will allow user to login to your app. But it does not support any way to check if the user is logged in in the facebook app.